# Android - Help with Calculator Logic

Tags: android, logic, calculator

I've made a custom dialog that is a simple calculator for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.  I'm having trouble getting the logic of my code correct. Does anyone have any word of wisdom or know of resource I could check out that could help.

Below is the code for my custom dialog and the calculator Logic that i'm working on. As it is all the calculations work fine except for when i use the equals button.  Calculation I do after that point don't come out right.

Thanks!

[Calculator http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/9534/devicee.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/9534/devicee.png)

```
public class CustomCalcDialog extends Dialog {

    public CustomCalcDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    EditText calcDialogDisplay;
    TextView enterTotal;
    TextView allClear;
    TextView seven;
    TextView eight;
    TextView nine;
    TextView division;
    TextView four;
    TextView five;
    TextView six;
    TextView multiply;
    TextView one;
    TextView two;
    TextView three;
    TextView subtract;
    TextView decimal;
    TextView zero;
    TextView equals;
    TextView addition;

    ArrayList<Float> mathVariables = new ArrayList<Float>();
    float mathVariable1;
    float mathVariable2;

    int currentOperation = 0;
    int nextOperation;

    final static int ADD = 1;
    final static int SUBTRACT = 2;
    final static int MULTIPLY = 3;
    final static int DIVISION = 4;
    final static int EQUALS = 5;

    final static int CLEAR = 1;
    final static int DONT_CLEAR = 0;
    int clearCalcDisplay = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator_dialog);

        calcDialogDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calc_dialog_display);
        enterTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enter_total);
        allClear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.all_clear);
        seven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nine);
        division =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.division);
        four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.five);
        six =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.six);
        multiply = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.three);
        subtract = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtract);
        decimal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.decimal);
        zero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zero);
        equals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equals);
        addition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addition);

        calcDialogDisplay.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));

        registerListeners();
    }

    public void registerListeners () {

        enterTotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activeTextView.setText(calcDialogDisplay.getText().toString());
                mathCalculations();
                CustomCalcDialog.this.dismiss();
            }
        });

        allClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                mathVariable1 = 0;
                mathVariable2 = 0;
                mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);
                currentOperation = 0;
                nextOperation = 0;                  
            }
        });

        seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("7");

            }
        });

        eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("8");

            }
        });

        nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("9");

            }
        });

        division.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(DIVISION);                    
            }
        });

        four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("4");

            }
        });

        five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("5");

            }
        });

        six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("6");

            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(MULTIPLY);

            }
        });

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("1");

            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("2");

            }
        });

        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("3");

            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(SUBTRACT);
            }               
        });

        decimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append(".");

            }
        });

        zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clearCalcDisplay == CLEAR) {
                    calcDialogDisplay.setText("");
                }
                clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR;
                calcDialogDisplay.append("0");

            }
        });

        equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(EQUALS);

            }
        });

        addition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calcLogic(ADD);
            }
        });
    }

    private void calcLogic(int operator) {

        mathVariables.add(Float.parseFloat(calcDialogDisplay.getText().toString()));

        if (operator != EQUALS) {
            nextOperation = operator;
        }else if (operator == EQUALS){
            nextOperation = 0;
        }

        switch (currentOperation) {
        case ADD:               
            mathVariable1 = mathVariables.get(0);
            mathVariable2 = mathVariables.get(1);

            mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);

            mathVariables.add(mathVariable1 + mathVariable2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.3f", mathVariables.get(0)));
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            mathVariable1 = mathVariables.get(0);
            mathVariable2 = mathVariables.get(1);

            mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);

            mathVariables.add(mathVariable1 - mathVariable2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.3f", mathVariables.get(0)));
            break;
        case MULTIPLY:
            mathVariable1 = mathVariables.get(0);
            mathVariable2 = mathVariables.get(1);

            mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);

            mathVariables.add(mathVariable1 * mathVariable2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.3f", mathVariables.get(0)));
            break;
        case DIVISION:
            mathVariable1 = mathVariables.get(0);
            mathVariable2 = mathVariables.get(1);

            mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);

            mathVariables.add(mathVariable1 / mathVariable2);

            calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.3f", mathVariables.get(0)));
            break;
        }

        clearCalcDisplay = CLEAR;
        currentOperation = nextOperation;
        if (operator == EQUALS) {
            mathVariable1 = 0;
            mathVariable2 = 0;
            mathVariables.removeAll(mathVariables);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an excellent picture.

Comment: What code do you currently have?  Where specifically are your problems?

Comment: I just added the code and what is happening.  The calculator logic is at the very end called "calcLogic".

Comment: I figured it out.  I basically had to reset the variables back to 0 at the end of the calcLogic.  I've updated the code to what is looks like now.  Everything seems to be working.  If there is anyone that has a better suggestion on how I should do my logic please let me know.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: if you are satisfied with your result, you might want to post it as an answer and accept it, so that others who have similar problems can find your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider separating your app into two parts. The gui gathers the input and selects the action. Now create another class to do the calculations, say Model.java. This class should provide methods that take parameters and provide a return value. Test these isolated methods for accuracy and invalid input, out of range values and senseless input. Design the exceptions for your model to throw. Now connect the GUI to the Model.